# Python multiprocessing.Queue File exists error under Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, multiprocessing, message-queue

I am getting a strange intermittent error when attempting to create a Queue from the multiprocessing module from Cygwin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    multiprocessing.Queue()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 213, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._rlock = Lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 117, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

The minimal code to reproduce this is just:

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.Queue()
```

though the error only occurs about 25% of the time.

Currently to "solve" this problem I just have a while loop which continually creates `Queue`s until the error doesn't show up, but I'd rather figure out why it is happening. I tried looking at the source files noted, but even tracing all the way back to the c source didn't shed any light.

I am running python 2.6.7 from Cygwin on Windows 7 64-bit. If I run this from cmd through my native windows python, i.e. not from Cygwin, the problem does not occur.

UPDATE:
Looking more closely at the source, it looks like the CreateSemaphore C function takes in a "name" parameter, and if a semaphore with this name already exists, then an error `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` will be flagged. However, in the python source in Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c, this function is called without a name parameter, so this should not happen. I'm guessing this is then just a quirk in cygwin's semaphore implementation.

Edit2:
I now have a setup as such:

```
import multiprocessing

for i in range(10):
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            q = multiprocessing.Queue()
            break
        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno == 17:
                count += 1
            else:
                raise # catch other errors, but this has never happened
    print "iterations %d" % count
```

I have noted a quirk: The number of times the Queue constructor will fail is always less than or equal to 3003, and exactly 3000 appears quite often as well. In addition, once the constructor has succeeded once, it will not fail again for the rest of the iterations of the for loop.

I am still stumped! I have tried playing with gc.collect, time.sleep, calling close or del on the queue itself, and none of these seem to have any impact. If this is indeed a problem with the operating system cleaning up semaphores, is there anyway to "force" this to happen via a system call?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Linux, seems to be a window specific issue. My guess is - it's a garbage collection issue with the queue's semaphore, maybe the way semaphores are identified on windows? but this is just a guess, my only input here is that it seems to be windows specific.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I installed a windows python version and tested that (should have done this first thing)... It looks like this is a Cygwin-specific problem.

Comment: Tested on Python 2.6.5 in Cygwin on Windows 7 and could not reproduce.

Comment: @gfortune Are you on 64-bit or 32? I tried python 2.6.5 as well and it still occurs.

Comment: uname -a from inside cygwin gives CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 ... 1.7.9(0.237/5/3)

Comment: I'm also on Win 7, python 2.6.7, cygwin 1.7.11 and it works fine.

Comment: Somewhat related... this fails for me on Windows 7 32-bit but works fine on 64-bit (cygwin, python 2.7.3): 

`import multiprocessing

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
q.put(1)
while not q.empty():
    q.get()`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
    wrelease()
ValueError: semaphore or lock released too many times`

Answer (score 2):

Also broken in cygwin *python 2.6.8*

```
$ python
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jun  9 2012, 11:30:32) 
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
```

The error  (below) is caused because `multiprocessing.futures` uses
`multiprocessing.queue`.  Bummer! I was hoping to use it as an alternative to
gevent (because gevent uses monkey patching)

```
$ ./eg3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./eg3", line 13, in <module>
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 275, in __init__
    EXTRA_QUEUED_CALLS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.6-cygwin-1.7.16-i686.egg/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 219, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.6-cygwin-1.7.16-i686.egg/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._rlock = Lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.6-cygwin-1.7.16-i686.egg/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 117, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.6-cygwin-1.7.16-i686.egg/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists
```